# How to protect Access database and limit to certain computers

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, copy-protection

Good morning,

I'm doing a project, the customer prefers to use Access 2013 as the all in one package - front end, database etc.

In short the customer will give their users a blank copy of the database, which is taken on site and used to generate data based on calibration of equipment for that site.

The problem is the customer doesn't want anyone being able to copy the access database and use it themselves.  So basically when on site he doesn't want the customer or anyone to go "oh that database is hand, give me a copy and I'll use it for myself".

I know I can compile the database but that will only protect the source.

Any suggestions on the best way to limit the use of the database?

Comment: You might be able to do something with the mac address of authorized computers. ref http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=216672

Comment: Hi Remou, I've been considering that also or the serial number of the motherboard, hard drive.  I'm just fielding the question to see if there are better options.

Comment: @JimBuckleyBarrett I like the motherboard SN idea, Microsoft historically used this as part of their validation that you had only installed a copy of windows on a single PC, no idea if that is still the case.

Comment: Yep, as they want to make multiple copies of the blank database, I'm going to look at compiling it and having them copy that.  When open if the license table is empty, admin user will have to enter their password to allow the database to continue.  At that stage I'll read the motherboard or hard drive serial number and use that as the reference.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years and I may be foggy on parts of this, but I know you can get around password protected databases, and can bypass the 'startup' form/code so that you can open the database and view all the objects. You are correct that an MDE will not show the code. But if you have a table of valid serial numbers or MAC Id's, then I would have a module that encrypts the data in that table. Otherwise someone could add their values and still run the program?  We also did some devious things like create an install package that would create some hidden file in some existing folder (with a calculated value as content), then if Access didn't find that file & content it would not run.

Comment: Hi Wayne, password protection on the old access database was a joke it was only to keep out "standard users".    Project has been put on hold by client so waiting on their decision on another matter before proceding.  Thanks for the reply.